# PHP using mysql_fetch_array to fill a table

Tags: php

Ok Before you tell me to use mysqli I am using the depreciated methods on purpose for a webapp lesson. I am not a student, this is not homework, it is to help me teach an understanding for web application security.

I cannot figure out why this wont work. Basically, All I want to do is create a page that takes the data from the mysql database and places it into a table as shown. At this point I am open to anything.

Thank you in advance.

```html
 <html>
 <head><title>Untitled</title></head>
 <body>
  <h1>Weblog Example</h1>
 <dl>
 <?php
   mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("blog1");
   $query ="SELECT entrytitle, entrytext,";
   $query.=" DATE_FORMAT(entrydate, '%M %d, %Y') AS entrydate";
   $query.=" FROM weblog ORDER BY entrydate DESC LIMIT 10";
   $result=mysql_query($query);
  
   ?>
   <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td width="15%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Title</strong></td>
<td width="75%" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Entry</strong></td>
<td width="15" align="center" bgcolor="#E6E6E6"><strong>Date/Time</strong></td>
</tr>
  
<?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['entrytitle']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['entrytext']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['entrydate']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

 </dl>
 </body>
</html>
```

Ok- made some minor edits- it now gives me 3 rows in the table but doesn't populate the data...

Comment: `date` is a reserved keyword, so try changing it to have the backticks in from ``date`` in your query.

Comment: because you're using `$entrytitle` and `$entrytext` instead of using `$row`

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());` which is something you're not doing, plus having error reporting on.

Comment: ElefantPhace nailed it. Had error reporting been set, would have signaled an undefined variable.

Comment: @ElefantPhace Actually, it's `$rows` ;) but you nailed it.

Comment: You can assign string variable in multi-line

Comment: Don't use short tags! change your `<? ` to `<?php `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both your `$query.=` should read as `$query .=` that alone will be an issue and will not concatenate properly because of the missing space before the dots.

You're also missing a `</table>` tag.

Plus, make sure that short tags are set/on, otherwise do `<?php echo $rows...`
instead of `<? echo $rows...`.

You should also check for possible query errors using:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

and using [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php).

Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

---

- I also suggest you switch to [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

---

Comment: That did it. Thank you! I am working on fixes now but the short tags were a part of the problem Error reporting is very helpful too. I appreciate your time, thank you everyone for looking.

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong variable in your while loop, you're also not referencing the correct `date` column from your query result.

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
<?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['entrytitle']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['entrytext']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['entrydate']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Read my comment under OP's question where I tagged you ;)

Comment: Oops my mistake, I'm used to it being simply `$row` since it is after all, a single row! Thanks @Fred-ii-!

Comment: Ok fixed, the mistakes. Now it creates 3 rows under the table but does not populate the data..

Comment: Hehe indeed! Was looking it over again and saw he had added in the changes and changed his query!

Answer (score 1):

Do a var_dump on $entrytitle and $entrytext and you'll understand you error.
Data is temporary stored into $rows when you do a mysql_fetch_array.

```
<?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows["entrytitle"]; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows["entrytext"]; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows["entrytext"]; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>
```